# Is there a source somewhere saying Sholay has copied from Jomeh?

Tags: copyright

I have found that the melody of the song "Haan Jab Tak Hai Jaan" in the 1975 Indian movie *Sholay* is exactly the opening melody of 1970 Iranian song *Jomeh* by Farhad Mehrad:

[Haan Jab Tak Hai Jaan](https://gaana.com/song/haa-jab-tak-hai-jaan)

[Jomeh](https://upmusics.com/%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF-%D8%A2%D9%87%D9%86%DA%AF-%D8%AC%D9%85%D8%B9%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AF/)

Is there a source somewhere relating the two works?